# D3.js-how to clip area outside rectangle while zooming in a grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

Here is the link to my code http://jsfiddle.net/qkHK6/2174/ .I want to hide or clip the area outside the rectangle.You can see from my jsfiddle that while zooming the bars move to the left of y-axis so i want to clip that area.Please someone help me with that.

```
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 300 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
//Data used for bar chart
var data = [{
  "State": "CA",
  "Under 5 Years": 2704659,
  "5 to 13 Years": 4499890,
  "14 to 17 Years": 2159981,
  "18 to 24 Years": 3853788,
  "25 to 44 Years": 10604510,
  "45 to 64 Years": 8819342,
  "65 Years and Over": 4114496
}, {
  "State": "TX",
  "Under 5 Years": 2027307,
  "5 to 13 Years": 3277946,
  "14 to 17 Years": 1420518,
  "18 to 24 Years": 2454721,
  "25 to 44 Years": 7017731,
  "45 to 64 Years": 5656528,
  "65 Years and Over": 2472223
}, {
  "State": "NY",
  "Under 5 Years": 1208495,
  "5 to 13 Years": 2141490,
  "14 to 17 Years": 1058031,
  "18 to 24 Years": 1999120,
  "25 to 44 Years": 5355235,
  "45 to 64 Years": 5120254,
  "65 Years and Over": 2607672
}, {
  "State": "FL",
  "Under 5 Years": 1140516,
  "5 to 13 Years": 1938695,
  "14 to 17 Years": 925060,
  "18 to 24 Years": 1607297,
  "25 to 44 Years": 4782119,
  "45 to 64 Years": 4746856,
  "65 Years and Over": 3187797
}, {
  "State": "IL",
  "Under 5 Years": 894368,
  "5 to 13 Years": 1558919,
  "14 to 17 Years": 725973,
  "18 to 24 Years": 1311479,
  "25 to 44 Years": 3596343,
  "45 to 64 Years": 3239173,
  "65 Years and Over": 1575308
}, {
  "State": "PA",
  "Under 5 Years": 737462,
  "5 to 13 Years": 1345341,
  "14 to 17 Years": 679201,
  "18 to 24 Years": 1203944,
  "25 to 44 Years": 3157759,
  "45 to 64 Years": 3414001,
  "65 Years and Over": 1910571
}];
var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);
```

colors used for different ages

```
 var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c",   "#ff8c00"]);



 creating axis and bar graph
```

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".1s"));

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 10]).on("zoom", zoom));

//d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
var ageNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key !== "State";
});
console.log("ageNames=" + JSON.stringify(ageNames));
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      value: +d[name]
    };
  });
  console.log("d.ages=" + JSON.stringify(d.ages));
});

x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.State;
}));
x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  console.log(" before retuen d.ages=" + d.ages);
  return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) {
    console.log("d.value;=" + d.value);
    return d.value;
  });
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".5em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Population");

var allStates = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "allStates");


var state = allStates.selectAll(".state")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "state")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)";
  });

state.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.ages;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  });
var legnColorGap = height / 17.5;
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(ageNames.slice().reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * legnColorGap + ")";
  });
var lwidth = width / 75,
  lht = height / 22,
  lwidth1 = lwidth + 2;
legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - lwidth1)
  .attr("width", lwidth)
  .attr("height", lht)
  .style("fill", color);
var textht = lht / 2,
  textwd = textht + lwidth;
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - textwd)
  .attr("y", textht)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });


  //Zooming Function 
function zoom() {
  svg.select(".allStates").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + ",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ",1)");
  svg.select(".x.axis").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + "," + (height) + ")").call(xAxis.scale(x0.rangeRoundBands([0, width * d3.event.scale], .5 * d3.event.scale)));
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tqn7162/1/)

It comes down to a few modifications. First, you need to know about [SVG `clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) which is a way to define an svg shape that masks or crops another shape (your chart, in this case). As demonstrated in the linked documentation, a `clip-path` requires a `<defs>` element with a `<clipPath>` inside it. In your case, that `<clipPath>` needs to contain a `<rect>` whose bounds are set to cover the visible area.

To create that `<defs>`, I added:

```
var mask = svg.append("defs")
  .append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "mask")
  .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .append("rect")
    .attr({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: width,
      height: height + margin.bottom,
    })
```

Ultimately, to use the above mask to crop the chart, it required calling

```
.attr("clip-path", "url(#mask)")
```

on the thing that is being masked.

The way you had things set up, there was no single SVG `<g>` that contained both of the things that needed to be mask (i.e. the chart and the x-axis). So I added that `<g>`, and reshuffled things so that the axis and chart (`allStates`) are added to it:

```
var masked = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#mask)")

masked.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

var allStates = masked
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "allStates");
```

And that's all.

Answer (score -1):

What about that?

```
function zoom() {
svg.select(".allStates").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + ",0)scale(" + d3.event.scale + ",1)");
svg.select(".x.axis").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate[0] + "," + (height) + ")").call(xAxis.scale(x0.rangeRoundBands([0, width * d3.event.scale], .5 * d3.event.scale)));
//svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
svg.select(".y.axis").attr("transform", "translate(" + (d3.event.translate[0]-d3.event.scale) + ", 0)")
}
```

I just added the last line to move the Y axis to the left when zooming.

Let me know if that's enough for you.