# How to zoom my stream-graph with using D3V6?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Update:**
The zooming stream graph question is resolved. Thank you, Andrew! But the zooming of the streamgraph doesn't align with the zooming of the X and Y axis.

[Thisis the picture showing how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3pk4.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6izi.png)

**the original post is here:**

I am new to StackOverflow and the javascript community. I am trying to zoom a streamgraph I did use javascript and D3 and I followed this tutorial: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_zoom.html#axisZoom.

My code can be viewed here: https://github.com/Feisnowflakes/zoomtest222/tree/main/streamgraph-test

However, currently, I can zoom X aXis and Y aXis, but not my stream graph is zoomable. I didn't see any errors in my console, so I am stuck now. Can anyone like to look at my codes and help me figure out why my streamgraph cannot be zoomed?

Thank you so much!

```js
(function () {
    // first, load the dataset from a CSV file


    d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Feisnowflakes/zoomtest222/main/streamgraph-test/Los_Angeles_International_Airport_-_Passenger_Traffic_By_Terminal.csv") 

        .then(data => {
            // log csv in browser console
            console.log(data);

            var advanceVisData = {};
            var airport = new Set();


            data.forEach(d => {
                airport.add(d['Terminal']);
                var period = new Date(d['ReportPeriod']);
                if (period in advanceVisData) {
                    if (d['Terminal'] in advanceVisData[period]) {
                        advanceVisData[period][d['Terminal']] += Number(d['Passenger_Count']);
                    }
                    else {
                        advanceVisData[period][d['Terminal']] = Number(d['Passenger_Count']);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    advanceVisData[period] = {};
                    advanceVisData[period][d['Terminal']] = Number(d['Passenger_Count']);
                }
            });

            console.log(airport);
            console.log(advanceVisData);
          

            // reformat the advanceVisData for d3.stack()
            var formattedData = [];
            Object.keys(advanceVisData).forEach(d => {
                var item = {};
                item['year'] = d;
                airport.forEach(terminal => {
                    if (terminal in advanceVisData[d]) {
                        item[terminal] = advanceVisData[d][terminal];
                    } else {
                        item[terminal] = 0;
                    }
                });
                formattedData.push(item);
            });
            console.log(formattedData);


            /*********************************
             * Visualization codes start here
             * ********************************/

            var width = 1200;
            var height = 400;
            var margin = { left: 60, right: 20, top: 20, bottom: 60 };
            //set the dimensions and margins of the graph



            // append the svg object to the body of the page
            var svg = d3.select('#container')
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            // List of groups = header of the csv files
            var keys = Array.from(airport);

            //stack the data?
            var stackedData = d3.stack()
                //.offset(d3.stackOffsetSilhouette)
                .keys(keys)
                (formattedData);
            console.log(stackedData);
            var max_val = 0;
            var min_val = 0;
            stackedData.forEach(terminal => {
                terminal.forEach(year => {
                    if (year[0] < min_val) min_val = year[0];
                    if (year[1] < min_val) min_val = year[1];
                    if (year[0] > max_val) max_val = year[0];
                    if (year[1] > max_val) max_val = year[1];
                })
            });
            //console.log(max_val, min_val);

            // Add X axis

            var x = d3.scaleTime()
                .domain(d3.extent(formattedData, function (d) {
                    return new Date(d.year);
                }))
                .range([0, width]);


            var xAxis = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(20));


            // Add Y axis
            var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([min_val, max_val])
                .range([height, 0]);
            var yAxis = svg.append("g")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

            // color palette
            var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                .domain(keys)
                .range(['#e41a1c', '#377eb8', '#4daf4a', '#984ea3', '#ff7f00', '#f781bf', "#87sbf", "#ff981bf","#d6a3b6", '#b3afb0', '#ddd8c2']);


            // create a tooltip
            var Tooltip = svg
                .append("text")
                .attr("x", 0)
                .attr("y", 0)
                .style("opacity", 0)
                .style("font-size", 17)



            // Show the areas
            var stream = svg.append("g")
            stream
                .selectAll(".myStreamArea")
                .data(stackedData)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", "myStreamArea")
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return color(d.key);
                })
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .attr("d", d3.area()
                    .x(function (d) {
                        return x(new Date(d.data.year));
                    })
                    .y0(function (d) {
                        return y(d[0]);
                    })
                    .y1(function (d) {
                        return y(d[1]);
                    })
                );

            // Set the zoom and Pan features: how much you can zoom, on which part, and what to do when there is a zoom
            var zoom = d3.zoom()
                .scaleExtent([.5, 20])  // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
                .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
                .on("zoom", updateChart);

            // This add an invisible rect on top of the chart area. This rect can recover pointer events: necessary to understand when the user zoom
            svg.append("rect")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("pointer-events", "all")
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
                .call(zoom);
            // now the user can zoom and it will trigger the function called updateChart

            // A function that updates the chart when the user zoom and thus new boundaries are available
            function updateChart() {

                // recover the new scale
                var transform = d3.zoomTransform(this);
                var newX = transform.rescaleX(x);
                var newY = transform.rescaleY(y);
                // var newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
                // var newY = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y);

                // update axes with these new boundaries

                xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX))
                yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY))


                stream
                    .selectAll(".myStreamArea")
                    .attr("d", d3.area()
                        .x(function (d) {
                            return newX(new Date(d.data.year));
                        })
                        .y0(function (d) {
                            return newY(d[0]);
                        })
                        .y1(function (d) {
                            return newY(d[1]);
                        }));
            }



        })
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zoomable streamgraph</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #tooltip {
        min-width: 100px;
        min-height: 50px;
        background-color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"> <div id="tooltip"></div></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any elements that have the tag `mylayers`, so `.selectAll("mylayers")` won't select anything in your update function, try `.selectAll(".myStreamArea")` - looks like you changed the class you were using to describe the areas as you went along. On side notes, the last enter cycle, under the 2nd comment of "show the areas" is redundant, and your mouse interaction area is off a bit (fill it with a color to see where it lies - I think you have applied the margin twice).

Comment: Thank you so much! I went back to my code and made changes based on your comments. Yes, now the streamgraph can be zoomed. But the new issue is the zooming of streamgraph doesn't align with the X axis and Y axis, it looks so weird. Do you want know why?

Comment: Based on the behavior I saw and what I believe your comment refers to, you'll need to implement a clip path for the plot area, so that as you zoom in the area doesn't exceed the plot area. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38051889/7106086) might be useful, though there may be more specific examples that I can't find right now...